# How do I remove the washing machine's outlet tube?

Tags: washing-machine

I have a washing machine drain tube that empties into a sink. The water that comes out is really sulfurous and stinks. I want to replace the tube, but I am not sure how to remove this. I would hire a plumber, but that seems like overkill. I should be able to remove this and buy a new one. Does anyone know what tools I need to do this?

[image]

I can remove the metal tension holder thingy, but it's still attached. There's a protruding white plastic piece that I don't want to accidentally break. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair of pliers. More conveniently, a pair of **locking pliers.**

Place the pliers on the projecting parts, and squeeze them together. This is a standard spring hose clamp. Pull the loosened clamp down the hose past the part it clamps on to, and then you can let go.

Then pull the hose off that part (twisting may help, but it's mostly pulling.) Moderate heating may help make the rubber a bit more pliable - those do tend to harden with age.

Don't discard the clamp - you may need it for the new hose.

Comment: Totally worked, new drain hose installed and fastened without leaks. Thank you!